# Combination question, number of ways 5 men and 5 women can marry

Tags: combinations

What is the number of ways $5$ men and $5$ women can marry? (if each person can only marry one person from opposite gender)
I have seen $5!$ because each gender can start from a person being able to choose 5 and then the next person can choose $4$ and so on, but i have seen $2\times5!$ suggesting it's different whether the choosing person is male or female, and another choice was $(5!)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It' 5!. Because whether man or woman choose firsf, we end up with the same couples. To make it clear you can try 2 men and 2 women